# Updating MySQL Workbench OS X Lion

Tags: mysql-workbench

I currently have version 5.2.37 and I want to update to 5.2.38. How do I do this and keep my DB connections? Are they stored outside of the application or will I have to recreate the connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your settings (stored server connection/instances, logs, preferences, etc.) are stored in a separate directory (`~/.mysql/workbench` in Linux/Mac OSX and `%APPDATA%/MySQL/Workbench` in Windows) and will not be affected when you upgrade. Once you do the upgrade you will see that all of your settings are in place and working.

It is a good idea to upgrade Workbench to 5.2.38 since it includes a lot of bug fixes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but I'd be astonished if your settings *weren't* kept. I'm not even sure that your settings could be kept inside the app itself. More likely they're kept in your home directory, somewhere under "Library".